# How can you implement a looping timer? Is it possible to vary the time delay?

Tags: excel, vba, timer, offset

I'm trying to make code which moves the active cell downwards every x seconds (with hopefully x<1), and am having some issues.

Firstly, the following line of code bugs out at the 4th line when I run it, saying: "Cannot run the macro "__". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled".

I cannot find any fixes for this online - is there an error in this Sub or is this an issue with my setup of Excel which can be easily fixed?

```
Public Sub Time_Practice()
    Debug.Print "Hello, it is " & Timer
    Timer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime Timer, "Time_Practice"
End Sub
```

Secondly, the actual code I would like to run is the stuff below, but where I can vary TimeValue("00:00:01") by using a variable such as Added_Time.

By this I mean, if something has happened Y times, I would like the new value for Added_Time = TimeValue("00:00:01") - 0.01 * Y (i.e. if it has happened 10 times, I would like the time gap to be 0.9 seconds).

Would the following line of code be valid and work ok?

```
Dim Timer As Double, Dim Y as Double
Public Sub Movement()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Timer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") - 0.01 * Y
    Application.OnTime Timer, "Movement"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Timer` is a keyword in VBA, so choose something else.    Also you might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116231/ontime-for-less-than-1-second-without-becoming-unresponsive

Comment: `Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") - ((0.01/(24*60*60)) * Y)`

Comment: `OnTime` only supports times in increments of 1s.  You'll need another approach to get <1s [see this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25116614/445425)