# How can I run a macro multiple times per second in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I'm currently trying to run a macro around five times per second using the Application.OnTime but it doesn't work with times less than a second. I know excel can handle my macro that many times as I've assigned it to a key and held it down. So is there any other way I can run my macro multiple times per second?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try a loop?

Comment: Try running a looped call to your function and set to break? Besides that, why would you need to recalculate several times per second? Excel really isn't the right tool for that

Comment: Did you check my code?

Comment: Maybe there is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116231/ontime-for-less-than-1-second-without-becoming-unresponsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Interval = 0.2
CurrentTime = Timer

Do While True
    If Timer > CurrentTime + Interval Then

        'Write your code here.
        
        Current = Timer
    End If
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks! This does run the code multiple times per seconds but other macros I call through inputs don't seem to run. Any ideas?

Comment: `
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "LeftMod"
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "RightMod"
    Application.OnKey Chr(32), "SpaceMod"
End Sub
`

`
Sub Loop()
 Interval = 0.2
 CurrentTime = Timer

 Do While True
  If Timer > CurrentTime + Interval Then
   hasMoved = False
   Current = Timer
  End If
  DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
`

Comment: So you have 3 functions like as "RightMod", "LeftMod" and "SpaceMod"?
Then you need to write my code in each function.
And could you tick my answer?

Comment: I just ticked it but the issue is that I am running your code when the user clicks a button. I want those input functions to work alongside your code

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: I run a macro with your code when the user clicks a button. I want your code to run throughout the rest of the time the user is interacting with my sheet, and it works. However, those inputs assigned to functions do not get called while your code is running. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: Here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/10f77dd995a154534c63dc463a813b0720210524052730/9470a3
Thanks for the help! Sorry if what I'm trying to do is weird

Comment: I just realized I have an extra End Sub at the start of the file. I accidentally left it there while cleaning up. It isn't the issue so you can just remove it.